# Project Euler 23 C++

Tags: c++

I have been working on **Project Euler #23.**

This is the task:

> Problem 23
>
> A perfect number is a number for which the sum of its proper divisors is exactly equal to the number. For example, the sum of the proper divisors of 28 would be 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28, which means that 28 is a perfect number.
>
> A number n is called deficient if the sum of its proper divisors is less than n and it is called abundant if this sum exceeds n.
>
> As 12 is the smallest abundant number, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16, the smallest number that can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers is 24. By mathematical analysis, it can be shown that all integers greater than 28123 can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers. However, this upper limit cannot be reduced any further by analysis >even though it is known that the greatest number that cannot be expressed as the sum of two abundant numbers is less than this limit.
>
> Find the sum of all the positive integers which cannot be written as the sum of two abundant numbers.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long sum;
    int numbers[30000];
    int ab[7000];

    for(int i=0;i<7000;i++)
        ab[i]=0;

    //array of numbers
    for(int i=0; i<28123;i++)
        numbers[i]=i+1;

    //abundant numbers
    int abud_counter=0;
    for(int i=1; i<28124;i++){

        //factors
        int temp=0;
        for(int j=2;j<=i/2;j++) {
            if(i%j==0)
                temp=temp+j;
        }
        temp=temp+1;
        if(temp > i) {
            ab[abud_counter]=i;
            numbers[i-1]=0;
            abud_counter=abud_counter+1;

            if(abud_counter>6965)
                break;
        }
    }

    //all shit
    int array2[7000];
    for(int i=0; i<6965; i++)
        array2[i]=ab[i];

    int k=0;
    for(int i=0;i<6965;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<6965;j++) {
            if(ab[i]+array2[j]==numbers[ab[i]+array2[j]-1]) {
                numbers[ab[i]+array2[j]-1]=0;
            }
        }
    }

    sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i<28123; i++) {
        sum = sum+numbers[i]; 
    }
    cout<<sum;
    return 0;
}
```

The total value I get is 4178876. The correct answer is 4179871.I have spent 10 hour looking at my code, but I am unable to find the error. What should I change to correct the error? My answer is close. Thanks in advance

PS. I am new to learning. Run time is 1.3s any optimisations will be useful as well.

Comment: "Run time is 1.3s any optimisations will be useful as well." - algorithmic improvements will provide the biggest win, but usually the compiler can also provide pretty nice speedups for most code, so make sure you enable your compilers optimizer. Debug builds (the default) are usually quite slow compared to Release builds that have compiler optimizations turned on.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the issue, but... _so many hardcoded values_!

Comment: You aren't checking that your sum is in less than 30000.

Comment: concerning optimizations: your approach is rather brute force. This isnt a bad thing to start with, but you could try a different perspective. For example, if a number is divisible by 12 then you already know that it is also divisible by 6,4,3 and 2. You also know that the contribution to the sum of divisors is 12+6+4+3+2 when a number is divisible by 12. Thats just one thought. Take the exercise as a opportunity to be creative ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems in the posted code, other than some inefficiencies and the abuse of magic numbers.

When the array of abundant numbers is filled, some elements of the `number` array are erroneously zeroed.

```
if(temp > i) {
    ab[abud_counter]=i;
    numbers[i-1]=0;               // <----- Why? Remove this line.
    abud_counter=abud_counter+1;
    if(abud_counter>6965)
        break;
}
```

When I tried this program, I got a segmentation fault, due to this line

```
for(int i=0;i<6965;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<6965;j++) {
        if(ab[i]+array2[j]==numbers[ab[i]+array2[j]-1]) {
            //                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   
            numbers[ab[i]+array2[j]-1]=0;
        }
    }
}
```

`numbers` has 30000 elements, but both `ab[i]` and `array2[j]` can have values up to 28123.

By the way, `array2` is redundant, beeing it just a copy of `ab`.

A modified version of your algorithm, which produces the correct value of 4179871, could be the [following](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yU3cYgZjvjieTYj2)

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

long sum_of_dividends(int n)
{
    long sum{1};
    int i = 2;
    for (int j = n; i < j; ++i)
    {
        if ( n % i == 0 )
        {
            sum += i;
            j = n / i;
            if (i == j)
               break;
            sum += j;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> abundants;
    abundants.reserve(7000);
    constexpr int max_value = 28123;
    for (int i{1}; i <= max_value; ++i)
    {
        if (sum_of_dividends(i) > i)
            abundants.push_back(i);
    }

    std::array<bool, max_value> are_sums{};

    for (unsigned i{}; i < abundants.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned j{i}; ; ++j)
        {
            long k = abundants[i] + abundants[j];
            if (k >= max_value)
                break;
            are_sums[k] = true;
        } 
    }
    long sum{};
    for (int i{}; i < max_value; ++i)
        if (!are_sums[i])
            sum += i;

    std::cout << sum << '\n';
}
```

While the previous implementation takes advantage of a faster method to calculate the sum of the dividends of a number, a drammatic improvement in processing time requires a different approach for the search of the abundant numbers.

The following snippet exploits an idea similar to the Sieve of Eratosthenes, instead of searching the dividends for every number in the range, it just sums every dividend of the appropriate number.

```
std::vector<int> abundants;
std::vector<long> dividends_sums(max_value + 1, 1);
for (int i{2}; i <= max_value; ++i)
{
    for (int j{i * 2}; j <= max_value; j += i)
        dividends_sums[j] += i;
    if (dividends_sums[i] > i)
        abundants.push_back(i);
}
```

The impact of this modification can be seen [here](http://quick-bench.com/5V8inN8YBMHMFPYuRESKoz9Q_zM).